# Azure AD Application - Manifest settings caching. Can I refresh this cache?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve a JWT from the management API in Azure using the following URL:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri={AppRedirectURL}&scope=openid&response_type=token

This is returning: `AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' is not supported for the application`

I've added the following to my application manifest:

`"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,`

But this is still giving me the error. I'm not sure why? I've logged my account in and out and tried from a private browsing window.

Does Azure cache details? Where can I refresh this cache within azure?

Comment: If you changed the manifest, it would just take a few seconds to complete the action. I don't think there is a cache within azure to cause this. Also, the `nonce` Parameter is also required in this Reqeust.

Comment: Also, ensure that you edited the manifest in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Looks like it was missing `nonce` and was a red herring error. Working now. Thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you missed adding `nonce` in the request.  The `nonce` Parameter is also required in this Reqeust.

Additional,If you changed the manifest, it would just take a few seconds to complete the action.

Comment: Manifest update did the trick, but it seems like the 'error' was caching because I was also missing the `nonce` in the request. Weird.